# position of div in particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one card window div in which

```
       <div id="cards_window"  class="popup_window ui-dialog ui-corner-all" title="Cards">
            <div id="cards_title">
                Cards <div id="cards_window_close" class="ui-button ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close popup_close"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="cards">
                <div id="cards_pending"><h3>Cards Pending</h3></div>
                <div id="cards_received"><h3>Cards Received</h3></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i am rendering in this the my all cards instances at particular positions and i want pending card to be in position in pending div and recievend in the received div for that 
what i should do but i am getting the div scattereed in the complete cards div.

Comment: can we check the page somewhere

Comment: Thats a loong sentance. Please try to describe the problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its done

```
<div id="cards_pending"><div style="clear: both;"><h3>Cards Pending</h3></div></div>\
<div id="cards_received"><div style="clear: both;"><h3>Cards Received</h3></div>
```